# Geopandas ImportError: The descartes package is required for plotting polygons in geopandas

Tags: python, error-handling, geopandas

I'am trying to run a simple geopandas code using ANACONDA spyder.  However, I'am encountering an error.

I have included the code and the error as below:

--

here is the code:

```
import geopandas as gpd
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
world.plot()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.show()
```

--

here is the error:

File "C:\Users\usr\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\plotting.py", line 90, in plot_polygon_collection
    "The descartes package is required for plotting polygons in geopandas."

ImportError: The descartes package is required for plotting polygons in geopandas.

--

I checked online and I couldn't find troubleshooting solution for this problem. Can anyone please help and advise?

appreciated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Depending on your package manager install descartes. In anaconda prompt do the following:

```
conda install descartes
```

Replace conda with pip or an other package manager of your use.

Answer (score 0):

The above didn't work for me. I ran the below command instead and it worked:

> pip install descarteslabs[complete]

Add `--user` on the end if you encounter any permissions errors